# open cart extension tell a friend not working

Tags: opencart

hi i have installed opencart extension tell a friend everything is good but email is not sending rest all emails when customer register and purchased are sending tell me the reason

here is the extension link also 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4348&filter_search=tell%20a%20friend

If some one has used this one please tell me

Comment: Can you check your error logs?

Comment: this question is off topic because it is about third party extension you should contact the extension developer to ask for support if you read the opencart tag excerpt you would know you should not ask such question here have a nice day and learn how to write in english so that anybody understands what is on your mind unless you are james joyce because every language has sentences that are delimited by dots if you do not care we do because we have to read your bulls'hits.

Comment: i have checked error log also no error at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**some time Opencart not work with emails on models. you need to put your logic in controller to fix this issue.**

here is the solution:
get all value in your Opencart controller function and put Email logic init something like this.

```
$mail = new Mail();

           $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');

           $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');

           $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');

           $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');

           $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');

           $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');

           $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');

           $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));

           $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);

           $mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);

           $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

           $mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

           $mail->send();
```